# WebView Object for scripting / Window.External

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to port my winforms app from WebBrowser to WebViewCompatible (using v5.1.1 or the prerelease v6 if need be) but i cant figure out how to make calls to window.external reference a custom POCO object.

In WebBrowser i just had to set BrowserControl.ObjectForScripting but i cant find any similar support in WebViewCompatible (i see a window.external.notify and its counterpart ScriptNotify event in WebView but even that would require a lot of hack work to if its even feasible )

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope i gave up, luckily including a compete polyfill gave me enough breathing room. The only way I can see around it is to use script notify with JSON messaging like it's 1992.

Comment: I have found a solution to intercept Click event in WebView. All is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326566/how-to-detect-click-on-div-element-contained-in-a-webview-control-on-visual/61347456#61347456